Is MySQL's MVCC Lock-Free?
I have a question about MVCC in MySQL.
The steps MySQL takes to update a row are as follows:
1.Acquire an exclusive lock.
2.First write to the undo log: record the pre-update data in the undo log and generate a pointer to the record in the undo log.
3.Then update the row: modify the transaction ID, modify the rollback pointer in the clustered index row, and change the data.
4.Write to the redo log: record the transaction ID, the rollback pointer, and the changes made to the data.
Then, online resources mention that MVCC is lock-free and achieves this through version chain lookup, where the starting point of the version chain is the row in the clustered index.
When reading, I first need to locate the row and check the transaction ID to see if it is visible in the read view.
If a read operation finds that this transaction ID is visible and then prepares to read the row, but another write operation with a higher transaction ID modifies the row, and the read operation does not lock, won't the read operation possibly read a partially modified row?
Is My Understanding of MySQL's MVCC Correct?

As I understand it, MVCC is not "lock-free". If you found a resource that says it is, you may want to post a link and/or direct quote. If there is verbiage that is more "brochurish" that implies it is in some way Superior to standard locking, that's not the same thing as NOT locking. Consider that when MySQL MYISAM locks a table for reading, other reads may still "play through" but writing is blocked until the read is completed. There are other schemas in different MySQL engines.

As I understand it, MVCC is not "lock-free". If you found a resource that says it is, you may want to post a link and/or direct quote. If there is verbiage that is more "brochurish" that implies it is in some way Superior to standard locking, that's not the same thing as NOT locking. Consider that when MySQL MYISAM locks a table for reading, other reads may still "play through" but writing is blocked until the read is completed. There are other schemas in different MySQL engines
